# Onedrive API vs LiveSDK

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, live-sdk, onedrive

I am developing for WP8.1 and probably will port on other platforms.
I want to integrate a OneDrive functionality, however, I can't understand what is the difference between `LiveSDK` (from NuGet packages) and `OneDrive` [API](https://dev.onedrive.com).

It seems that `Microsoft` does not communicate at all regarding that, I really don't understand why. As far as I understood, the `LiveSDK` is the old one and will be replaced by `OneDrive API`, but the `LiveSDK` seems so much simpler to use that I can't understand their logic... On top of that both have been updated recently (in April for the `LiveSDK`).

#### So my question is

- As long as my app has not been published yet, should I move to
  `OneDrive API`, or keep on the `LiveSDK`?
- Does anyone has already
  tried both?
- What are the limitations and benefits of both?

Based on a future-proof sight, I will go for the `OneDrive API`, but my main concern is:

**Is is possible to login as easily on `OneDrive API` than with the `Live SDK`? (Working temporary solution below)**

For now, I have been able to login with the `LiveSDK` using a single button and three lines of code, no user input required at all, where the `AuthenticateAndContinue` method used by the `OneDrive API` opens a Webcontrol and requires to enter manually the login and password.

At the end I have used the `LiveSDK` Authentication and use the access token provided with the `OneDrive API`. It is not a clean approach from my point of view, but I couldn't manage to get the `AuthenticateAndContinue` method to work (I get a 404 error answer after the login).

If anybody has a better solution, I am opened to suggestions :)

Comment: I have solved my issue (waiting for the new OneDrive API SDK to improve), but I would be happy for any suggestion allowing to authenticate using a "cleaner" way.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation Jean, where did you find the relevant resources? I still don't know how to hook OneDrive to my WP 8.1 application. I want to upload a file to OneDrive from my WP 8.1 App, any resources?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. To be honest, I am still unable to download properly a file using the background downloader (the transfer never ends and the file is not written on the phone).
There are some samples on there https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-win but unfortunately when I use my own code it does not work as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution extracted from question to get out of "unanswered" stack]

In summary, my current method is the following:

1. Authenticate using LiveSDK API
2. Use the session cookie and the OneDrive API from there

The simplified code is the following:

**The method below allows to log in silently, only the first time requires a manual validation from the user allowing the program to use its `Live` account.**

**It does not require any password from the user**

```
var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
var authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] {  
        "wl.signin", "onedrive.readwrite", "onedrive.appfolder"});

if (authResult.Session == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("You need to sign in and give consent to the app.");

var Connection = new ODConnection("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0", 
    new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationInfo() { TokenType = "Bearer", 
    AccessToken = odArgs.Session.AccessToken });
```

It is not as clean as I would like (using 2 different SDK), but it works :)